# Авторизация для одного устройства (game server)

Tags: c#, auth, redis, token

Требуется сделать авторизацию для игры, таким образом, что бы для одного аккаунта можно было авторизоваться только на одном устройстве. В голову пришла только такая идея:

При авторизации клиент получает токен, также этот токен хранится в хранилище Redis. При каждом обращении к сокету клиент присылает свой токен, он сверяется с токеном в хранилище, и если токен совпадает, то генерируется новый токен, обновляется в хранилище и так же отсылается обратно клиенту вместе с полученными данными.

Например, кто-то украл токен пользователя, подставил себе, и обратился к сокету, получится так, что токен в хранилище обновится, и предыдущее устройство теряет авторизацию.

Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть какая то стандартная схема авторизации одного устройства?

Comment: Надёжнее один раз генерировать сертификат, и все данные подписывать им со стороны клиента, в пакете всегда иметь хеш от клиента с уникальными данными, серийными hdd,mb, имя машины + логин. Сервер тоже имеет свой сертификат, который и является root для выписанного клиенту. Ключ сервера публичный, записывается жёстко в клиент аппликацию. И не надо токенов, это модно, но эффективно. Проверка всех пакетов будет проходить на уровне реализованного серверного протокола.

Comment: А какие минусы в моей реализации, может где то есть дыра, которую я не заметил ? С виду кажется нормально )

Comment: Безумно много телодвижений с открытыми по сути токенами, вопрос их клонирования кажется не составит труда, если будет достаточно желания.

Comment: Токен, это хеш, его должен генерировать клиент, на основании уникальной информации включая номера устройств итд где это запущено. Это и является уникальным логином. Соответственно если что то изменится в экосистеме, то данный токен (хеш) перестанет быть валидным в принципе. При выписке сертификата этот токен заносится в поле CN например. Подделать такую схему целиком на всех этапах маловероятно.

Comment: Клонировать токен в redis не получится, ведь он может быть создан только для одной учетной записи, то есть предполагается уникальность токена. Передавать можно и хеш токена, но тогда сопрут хеш и отправят его.

Comment: Пока не будет криптования и привязки к оборудованию, спереть можно что угодно на любом этапе :)

Comment: Сейчас у меня клиент хранит токен в зашифрованном виде, ключом шифрования является как раз идентификатор устройства. Получается что украв шифрованный токен его распаковать можно только зная идентификатор, но и его можно утащить у клиента, или эмулировать устройство )

Comment: По факту как то закрыть токен от злоумышленника не получится, постоянное обновление токена или еще чего в redis по сути спасет сервер от двойной авторизации, а то, что пользователь потеряет свой токен, мне почему то кажется, что это проблема пользователя, если я не несу ересь ))

Comment: Надёжным на текущий момент может считаться только ассемитричное шифрование, где вы можете проверить источник подписи.

Answer (score 0):

Тема, на самом деле, очень обширная. Вариантов реализации уйма.

1. > При каждом обращении к сокету клиент присылает свой токен

   Не нужно токен присылать. По хорошему, нужно прикладывать хэш от передаваемых данных, а не сам токен. Сервак реальным токеном тоже потом получает хеш от данных, если хеши совпадают, то считаем, что токен валиден.
2. > то генерируется новый токен, обновляется в хранилище и так же
   >   отсылается обратно клиенту вместе с полученными данными.

   Токен нужно генерировать только при авторизации.
3. Хранить нужно и в Редиске, и в основном хранилище (MySQL, Postres и т.п). После сверки хешей, если они не совпадают, обращаться в основное хранилище за реальным токеном. Обновлять токен в редисе и перепроверять хеш с новым токеном из основной базы.

Comment: Каким образом "Сервак реальным токеном тоже потом получает хеш от данных" ? серверу ведь придется лезть в базу за токеном

Comment: @webkostya ну да, придётся. И? )

Comment: Запросов по сокету может быть 60 раз в ссекунду, потом умножаем хотя бы на 1к пользователей, и получаем 60к запросов к базе в секунду, многовато, я хотел ограничить запросы в базу.

Comment: @webkostya вам в базу в любом случае стучаться придётся. Даже в вашем варианте.

Comment: в базу придется стучатся только если кто то спер мой токен и он не совпадает с токеном в redis, а так с базой работать надо только по запросу (если юзеру что то надо).

Comment: @webkostya а, вы про основную базу. В моём случае также. В базу основную стучаться нужно либо если в Редисе вообще токена нет, либо если после проверки хеши не совпадают.

Comment: В итоге рабочая схема такая: шлем токен серверу, он сверяет присланный токен с токеном в redis, если совпадает, то генерирует новый, обновляется в redis и отдается клиенту, получается каждый запрос новый токен у клиента и в redis, в базу лезем только если не сопадение. Если что то напутал то поправьте )

Comment: @webkostya зачем вам каждый раз новый токен генерить? Это нужно делать только при авторизации.

Comment: А если украдут токен, и подставят себе, то спокойно смогут пройти авторизацию, и получится 2 клинта в одной учетной записи.

Comment: @webkostya поэтому нужно не токен передавать, а хеш от данных. Тогда токен никто украсть в принципе не сможет.

Comment: Токен всегда можно украсть, пришел к другу и спер его ), просто надо исключить любую возможность аторизации с двух устройств